# How to add arguments to the function passed in request.addfinalizer() of pytest?

Tags: python-3.x, request, arguments, pytest, finalizer

I am writing a test suite with pytest. It looks like this.

```
@pytest.fixture
def f(request):
    ...
    def fin(arg):
        ...
        return

    request.addfinalizer(fin)
```

I am wondering if 'arg' would be taken into account inside off 'addfinalizer'?
Or is it a way to do that?

Comment: It won't be taken into account and nor do I see a way to do that as per what I checked in the code of `addfinalizer`.

Comment: Where should `arg` come from? You don't define it anywhere.

Comment: looks like no answer here sadly

Answer (score 3):

You can pass a lambda like this:

```
@pytest.fixture
def f(request):
    ...
    def fin(arg):
        ...
        return

    request.addfinalizer(lambda: fin(some_arg_here))
```

Answer (score 1):

use a functools.partial or a lambda